# Connect to database using javascript

Tags: javascript, mysql

I want to connect to a mysql database using javascript.

If it is possible, how can I do this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can JavaScript connect with MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3020751/can-javascript-connect-with-mysql)

Answer (score 2):

You could use [AJAX](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) to send a request to your server side script which will query the MySQL database. Javascript has no way of accessing a SQL database directly because it runs on the client. Imagine if this was possible: it would mean that anyone from his client computer would be able to send any SQL query he likes to your MySQL server which hopefully is not possible.