# How to use a mysql database in firefox os?

Tags: php, mysql, operating-system, marketplace, firefox-os

I have an instant messaging application on the web with its database and almost finished [M2S](http://message2space.es.vu). I want to make an application for firefox you without having to go through my website and I can do it if I have to call the mysql database?

Comment: @DannyBeckett Actually: http://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/partners/

Comment: @DannyBeckett please read https://developer.mozilla.org/ro/docs/Mozilla/Firefox_OS/Compilarea_si_instalarea_Firefox_OS

Comment: It seems I'm mistaken... interesting! Retagged.

Comment: It's not exactly what you're asking, but from a security perspective, you're better off presenting an API from your app server and letting it talk directly to mysql using its own credentials.  Your FFOS app would use API calls through that app server to read/persist data from the database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since Firefox OS is comprised of HTML5 technologies, it is currently not possible to connect directly to a MySQL server using the tools available at this time.

See here:

[Related Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3020751/can-javascript-connect-with-mysql)