# I need to use Database API to access the database how to do that?

Tags: javascript, mysql

Actually I am developing a web portal for this purpose I need to use the Database API of different servers to access the details of database. I am using JAVA SCRIPT as frontend language and MYSQL as the backend. Please give an example How can I use APIs for this purpose

Thank u in advance

Comment: Long discussion here [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3020751/can-javascript-connect-with-mysql][1], I suggest to close this one as a duplicate.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3020751/can-javascript-connect-with-mysql

Answer (score 1):

You cannot. Javascript only has APIs for a [limited set of storage frameworks](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/features/storage). MySQL is not one of them. You would need some server side language.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript is client side scripting language. You can't call database using JavaScript. Use any server side programming like Node JS, PHP, Java etc.

Comment: but my question is that how can I use database API to access database

Comment: @nitesh : as Masud mentioned, you need to use server side API and expose it via REST to your javascript.

Comment: @rkosegi : I have servers API then i don't know how to expose it? means how to write program whose using this API please give an example