# Connect javascript to access database

Tags: javascript, database

You wanna know if i can connect my website in javascript to a acess database,if i can how i can do it?
This is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<!--Here you will create a polygon by tools that Google maps "drawingManager" gives to you and then you have an array named "coordinates" as an output. This array saves all latLng of the polygon. When you edit the polygon it also edit this variable too.
!-->

<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true&libraries=drawing"></script>

<!--Global variables!-->
<script>
//This variable gets all coordinates of polygone and save them. Finally you should use this array because it contains all latitude and longitude coordinates of polygon.
var coordinates = [];

//This variable saves polygon.
var polygons = [];
</script>

<script>
//This function save latitude and longitude to the polygons[] variable after we call it.
function save_coordinates_to_array(polygon)
{
    //Save polygon to 'polygons[]' array to get its coordinate.
    polygons.push(polygon);

    //This variable gets all bounds of polygon.
    var polygonBounds = polygon.getPath();

    for(var i = 0 ; i < polygonBounds.length ; i++)
    {
        coordinates.push(polygonBounds.getAt(i).lat(), polygonBounds.getAt(i).lng());
        alert(i);
    }   
}
</script>

<script>
function initialize()
{
    //Create a Google maps.
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'),
     {zoom: 12, 
     center: new google.maps.LatLng(32.344, 51.048)});

    //Create a drawing manager panel that lets you select polygon, polyline, circle, rectangle or etc and then draw it.
    var drawingManager = new google.maps.drawing.DrawingManager();
    drawingManager.setMap(map);

    //This event fires when creation of polygon is completed by user.
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(drawingManager, 'polygoncomplete', function(polygon) {
        //This line make it possible to edit polygon you have drawed.
        polygon.setEditable(true);

        //Call function to pass polygon as parameter to save its coordinated to an array.
        save_coordinates_to_array(polygon);

        //This event is inside 'polygoncomplete' and fires when you edit the polygon by moving one of its anchors.
        google.maps.event.addListener(polygon.getPath(), 'set_at', function () {
            alert('changed');
            save_coordinates_to_array(polygon);
            });

        //This event is inside 'polygoncomplete' too and fires when you edit the polygon by moving on one of its anchors.
        google.maps.event.addListener(polygon.getPath(), 'insert_at', function () {
            alert('also changed');
            save_coordinates_to_array(polygon);
            });
    });
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
</head>

<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:AccessDataSource id="AccessDataSource1" runat="server">
    </asp:AccessDataSource>
    <asp:AccessDataSource id="AccessDataSource2" runat="server">
    </asp:AccessDataSource>
    <div id="map" style="width:1024px; height:768px;">
    </div>
</form>
</body>

</html>
```

What i wanna do is save the coordinates in database, and get the coordinates from database too,sure.
This is possible?

Comment: i think it is not possible if it is not rhino or nodejs, correct me if i am wrong

Comment: This is a repeat question, short answer : NO, see this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3020751/can-javascript-connect-with-mysql

Comment: Possible, but not recommended. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/857670/how-to-connect-to-sql-server-database-from-javascript I can feel drool forming as I think about this on a production site.

Answer (score 1):

Someone has probably figured out a way to do it however in my opinion it's a very bad idea. You'd be exposing your database connection information to anyone who has access to your javascript (assuming it's a typical website) this is... everyone. This leaves the door wide open for all kind of hackers.

The most common way to do this is to use some kind of server side language such as C#/VB.NET or php (although there are many many others).

Your Javascript calls the server side with ajax, your server side code connects to the database and returns a response.