# How to fetch data from MySQL only using HTML and JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, mysql

I want to access MySQL database on my local machine only using HTML and JavaScript. I don't want to involve any scripting which would require a webserver.
How to achieve this?

Comment: You will need server side scripting or any webservice which have manipulated mysql data...

Comment: possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3020751/can-javascript-connect-with-mysql

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for [Ajax](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/) it seems

> AJAX is the art of exchanging data with a server, and updating parts of a web page - without reloading the whole page.

As @Rayon implied... You will need server side scripting.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript can only do stuff on the client ( **or Node.js?** ). You must use a server-side scripting language like `PHP` to get information from a `MySQL` database.

You can use `AJAX` to pull information.

Comment: node.js has the ability to connect to mysql with the right package: on npm you can find it as mysql.

Answer (score 0):

You can use node.js for this purpose.