# I'm trying to build a basic website to display data from MySQL. Is there anyway to do this using just javascript and HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, mysql

I'm trying to build a basic website to display data from MySQL. Is there anyway to do this using just JavaScript and HTML? I feel like this is a simple task...but I'm still new to programming, so I'm having a hard time piecing everything together. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is this still client/server side?

Comment: You can not post data to the server just using javascript. You need also PHP in order to interact with server.

Comment: PHP is one language, not the only option on the server. But you do need something on the server. If you use Node.js, that could be Javascript.

Comment: Little disappointing you didn't google javascript connect to mysql. You would have found an answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can JavaScript connect with MySQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3020751/can-javascript-connect-with-mysql)

Answer (score 0):

No, **JavaScript** can not directly connect to **MySQL**. But you can mix **JS** with **PHP** to do so.

JavaScript is a client-side language and your **MySQL** database is going to be running on a server ([Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3020751/can-javascript-connect-with-mysql))

Also try searching for a post before duplicating it next time!