# Can I run a SQL query in frontend Javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, sql

I want to run a SQL query in a .JS file. I tried to add some PHP codes to it but it didn't work of course.

I want to run the SQL query: `SELECT price FROM list WHERE q=1`. I want to show the price in the chart. Does anyone know how I can run this SQL query in the .JS file so I can get the item price from the database?

I am using the following JavaScript code:

```
 /* Morris.js Charts */
  // Sales chart
  var area = new Morris.Area({
    element: 'revenue-chart',
    resize: true,
    data: [
      {y: '2016 Q1', item1: 5000, item2: 4460},
      {y: '2016 Q2', item1: 8432, item2: 5713}
    ],
    xkey: 'y',
    ykeys: ['item1', 'item2'],
    labels: ['Item 1', 'Item 2'],
    lineColors: ['#a0d0e0', '#3c8dbc'],
    hideHover: 'auto'
  });
  var line = new Morris.Line({
    element: 'line-chart',
    resize: true,
    data: [
      {y: '2015 Q4', item1: 0},
      {y: '2016 Q1', item1: 5000},
      {y: '2016 Q2', item1: 8432}
    ],
    xkey: 'y',
    ykeys: ['item1'],
    labels: ['Item 1'],
    lineColors: ['#efefef'],
    lineWidth: 2,
    hideHover: 'auto',
    gridTextColor: "#fff",
    gridStrokeWidth: 0.4,
    pointSize: 4,
    pointStrokeColors: ["#efefef"],
    gridLineColor: "#efefef",
    gridTextFamily: "Open Sans",
    gridTextSize: 10
  });
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can JavaScript connect with MySQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3020751/can-javascript-connect-with-mysql)

Answer (score 6):

You can't execute a query using javascript because javascript can't connect directly with your database, but you can use AJAX. With this technology you'll be able to send a request to a PHP (or other server side language) page where resides the code that can execute a query to your db and get back the result of this query.

You can find some information about client server here:

https://spin.atomicobject.com/2015/04/06/web-app-client-side-server-side/

http://www.codeconquest.com/website/client-side-vs-server-side/

And you can find a lot of useful information about ajax here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX/Getting_Started

Take a look even to jQuery for manage Ajax call:
http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

**EDIT**
You can use server side javascript to access your database, [here](http://The%20MySQL%20Cluster%20JavaScript%20Driver%20for%20Node.js%20is%20just%20what%20it%20sounds%20like%20it%20is%20%E2%80%93%20it%E2%80%99s%20a%20connector%20that%20can%20be%20called%20directly%20from%20your%20JavaScript%20code%20to%20read%20and%20write%20your%20data.%20As%20it%20accesses%20the%20data%20nodes%20directly,%20there%20is%20no%20extra%20latency%20from%20passing%20through%20a%20MySQL%20Server%20and%20need%20to%20convert%20from%20JavaScript%20code//objects%20into%20SQL%20operations.%20If%20for%20some%20reason,%20you%E2%80%99d%20prefer%20it%20to%20pass%20through%20a%20MySQL%20Server%20(for%20example%20if%20you%E2%80%99re%20storing%20tables%20in%20InnoDB)%20then%20that%20can%20be%20configured.) you can find a good article about MySql Cluster.
In a nutshell:

> The MySQL Cluster JavaScript Driver for Node.js is just what it sounds
>   like it is – it’s a connector that can be called directly from your
>   JavaScript code to read and write your data. As it accesses the data
>   nodes directly, there is no extra latency from passing through a MySQL
>   Server and need to convert from JavaScript code//objects into SQL
>   operations. If for some reason, you’d prefer it to pass through a
>   MySQL Server (for example if you’re storing tables in InnoDB) then
>   that can be configured.

Answer (score 5):

You cannot connect to Mysql directly from client side JS, but only from server side JS, such as `node`. It can just like PHP connect using PDO or mysqli extensions, run your query and then pass the information to client side JS.

Answer (score 3):

You can't directly connect to mysql with javascript but you can echo out your php variable in javascript like this..

```
 var area = new Morris.Area({
element: 'revenue-chart',
resize: true,
data: [
  {y: '2016 Q1', item1: <?php echo $price ?>, item2: <?php echo $price ?>},
  {y: '2016 Q2', item1: 8432, item2: 5713}
]
```

you can cover the whole javascript inside php script.

this will replace like this on executing.

```
{y: '2016 Q1', item1: 12054, item2: 65242},
```

Answer (score 2):

Execute your query out side the JS and pass the prices in the javascript .

Example :

```
$res_price = $conn -> query("SELECT price FROM list WHERE q=1");
$row_price = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res_price);

echo $row_price['price'];
```

Now in Javascript add Like,

```
<?php echo $row_price['price']; ?>
```

If you want add more than one prices then you can manage it through array also make array of price and pass it in the js.

Answer (score 0):

MyServerless can direct write Java and SQL in js, like below:

import * as my from "@/myserverless/myserverless.js"

my.$qryString(`#AdminRole select * from user where user_id=?`, 123);

Write SQL in JS is not safe, but for develop stage is OK, the trick is before deploy, extract SQL from front-end to back-end.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).