# Connect MySQL with PHP but query MySQL through JS?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

Is it possible? I don't want to use PHP for querying, so can I use it only for the connection while using javascript code for the query?

It'd be great if someone can provide an example of it.

Comment: you can't use javascript on client side to connect directly to the database, you have to use API

Comment: Not possible, your database is at the server-side, and can be accessed from the server only.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Run a SQL query in JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37453671/run-a-sql-query-in-js)

Comment: You can use Node?

Comment: Use AJAX if possible otherwise you can't add query in js

Comment: The idea that you could create a database connection in one language, and then use it in a different one, is already absurd enough to begin with.

Comment: @Teemu well, one could simply open up the db ports to the public .... ;)

Comment: @JonasWilms Indeed, I wouldn't do that though, and I suppose you wouldn't either.

Answer (score 1):

You can't query MySQL through JS because by default JS is clientside meaning it has no direct access to the databse server. If that were possible then anyone could just edit your JS and query whatever they want from the DB.

You can potentially use AJAX to call a PHP function from inside your JS code but all database queries have to be done through PHP since that's where you create the connection.

If you wanted to build your own request in JS then you'd have to switch to a framework like AngularJS or Node.js where the back-end is written in JS rather than PHP, but these are more complex.

Comment: For sure you *can* but as you point out in your second sentence *you don't want that*

Comment: @JonasWilms True, I just did it. Installed serverside js and now I'm able to query through it.