# How to execute php through javascript

Tags: javascript, php, backbone.js

I am currently using PHP with Backbone.js and in some places I am using PHP to interact with my MySQL server and fill the frontend with Backbone/javascript.

This is the sample PHP I am trying to execute.

```
$query="select id,username,message,useremail,date from contact";
$result =mysqli_query($connection,$query);
if ($result) {
    echo '<table id="hor-minimalist-b" summary="Users List">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col">User ID</th>
            <th scope="col">User Name</th>
            <th scope="col">User Message</th>
            <th scope="col">User Email</th>
            <th scope="col">Date</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>';
    while($resultarray=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
        echo "
        <tr>
            <td>{$resultarray['0']}</td>
            <td>{$resultarray['1']}</td>
            <td>{$resultarray['2']}</td>
            <td>{$resultarray['3']}</td>
            <td>{$resultarray['4']}</td>
        </tr>
        ";
    }
    echo "</tbody>
    </table>";
}
```

One way is to make a PHP file and make a ajax request to get the HTML output and append in a `div` container. But since I have way too many PHP code snippets, I wanted to somehow use javascript to ease me, since I am implementing backbone (http://myurl/#link/feed).

Currently, I tried an ugly way: using HTML and calling javascript functions through PHP's `echo`.

Comment: What you would need to make is a REST API with PHP, exposing your data from the server through different url endpoint used by backbone models and collections.

Comment: Thats is my final motive. But shifting whole lot of code from php to models and collections is hectic. I am shitfing gradually.

Comment: Also, PHP can return anything, it's not limited to HTML. So you could return JSON which javascript can easily parse.

Comment: Gradually integrating Backbone into an existing PHP website is shooting yourself in the foot. Backbone shines when used correctly within a single-page app.

Comment: Could you guide me a smooth way to make a DB query using backbone? And yes, my whole site is one page app, with too many pages powering it from behind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A summary of my comments:

> Gradually integrating Backbone into an existing PHP website is
>   shooting yourself in the foot. Backbone shines when used correctly
>   within a single-page app feeding its data from a RESTful API.
>
> What you would need is to make a REST API with PHP, exposing your data
>   from the server through different url endpoints used by backbone models
>   and collections. PHP can return anything, it's not limited to HTML, so
>   you could return JSON which javascript can easily parse.

## How to use Backbone with PHP

### The backend API

Here's a really simple PHP endpoint based on your code.

**example_ajax.php**

```
<?php
$query ="select id,username,message,useremail,date from contact";
$result = mysqli_query($query);
$rows = array();
while($r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $rows[] = $r;
}

// return the array as JSON so Backbone can automatically parse it.
print json_encode($rows);
```

See [Creating a simple REST API in PHP](https://www.leaseweb.com/labs/2015/10/creating-a-simple-rest-api-in-php/)

There are PHP frameworks that handle REST API for you, like:

- [Silex](http://silex.sensiolabs.org/) (micro-framework based on [Symfony](https://symfony.com/))
- [Slim](http://www.slimframework.com/)
- [Lumen](https://lumen.laravel.com/) (light-weight [Laravel](https://laravel.com/))
- [Phalcon](https://docs.phalconphp.com/fr/latest/reference/tutorial-rest.html)

### The frontend data handling

Create a custom collection which binds to our newly created endpoint:

```
var ContactCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    url: "example_ajax.php",
});
```

### The static template

And handle the HTML templating with Backbone views.

First prepare the HTML template, could be a static HTML on the server.

```
<table id="hor-minimalist-b" summary="Users List">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col">User ID</th>
            <th scope="col">User Name</th>
            <th scope="col">User Message</th>
            <th scope="col">User Email</th>
            <th scope="col">Date</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody></tbody>
</table>

<script type="text/template" id="contact-template">
    <td><%= id %></td>
    <td><%= username %></td>
    <td><%= message  %></td>
    <td><%= useremail %></td>
    <td><%= date %></td>
</script>
```

### Backbone views

Then the views:

```
var ContactView = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName: 'tr',
    template: _.template($('#contact-template').html()),
    initialize: function(options){
        // optional, automatically remove the html of this row only.
        this.listenTo(this.model, 'remove', this.remove);
    },
    render: function() {
        this.$el.empty().append(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
        return this;
    },
});
```

The list view below uses the `ContactView` as a child view.

```
var ContactListView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: "#hor-minimalist-b", // uses existing element in the page

    initialize: function(options) {
        // cache a jQuery element to use as a container for the child views.
        this.$body = this.$('tbody');

        // optional, automatically adds a new contact when the collection changes
        this.listenTo(this.collection, 'add', this.renderContact);
    },
    render: function() {
        this.$body.empty();
        this.collection.each(this.renderContact, this);
        return this; // always return this for chaining
    },

    renderContact: function(model) {
        var view = new ContactView({ model: model });
        this.$body.append(view.render().el);
    },
});
```

## How to use it

```
var collection = new ContactCollection(),
    view = new ContactListView({ collection: collection });
view.render();

collection.fetch();
```

The `.fetch()` function makes a GET call to something like `http://www.example.com/example_ajax.php`, which should return an array.

## Why an API? Why not send SQL queries from JavaScript?

JavaScript runs on the client side, which you should **never trust**. Instead, you expose specific endpoints on your server, which you can trust. This is why you need an API.

Sending SQL queries from javascript is a bad idea for several reasons:

- [SQL Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection): Someone could fetch/change anything in your database (including stealing password, or nuking the database all together),
- It's an open door to your server,
- Lacks trusted validation, or it's harder to validate a SQL query string,
- Tight coupling, e.g. making it harder to share queries code between different client (mobile app, website, desktop app, etc)

### It can be done, but it shouldn't.

[phpMyAdmin](https://www.phpmyadmin.net/) is an example of an application which takes SQL written by the user and runs it as-is.

If it's in a controlled environment, like a local intranet, and you want to access MySQL from client-side JavaScript, you could write a php script which takes the body of a request and pass it directly to a MySQL database, returning the result as JSON.

For example, there's a lib named [Squel.js](https://hiddentao.com/squel/) which serve to build SQL query strings. They have a big red box on the frontpage which reads:

> NOTE: It is recommended that you do NOT create queries browser-side to
>   run on the server as this massively increases your exposure to [SQL Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks.

Additionnal reading:

- [Is there any reason not to go directly from client-side Javascript to a database?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/180012/is-there-any-reason-not-to-go-directly-from-client-side-javascript-to-a-database)
- [Can JavaScript connect with MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3020751/can-javascript-connect-with-mysql)
- [What exactly is RESTful programming?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/671118/what-exactly-is-restful-programming)
- [Best Practices for Designing a Pragmatic RESTful API](http://www.vinaysahni.com/best-practices-for-a-pragmatic-restful-api)

Comment: I guess until something new comes out that could communicate javascript with mysql, this is my optimal choice. Thanks for briefing, i really appreciate it.

Comment: @unkn0wn since it was too long for a comment, I responded to you through an edit in my answer. I understand what you're trying to achieve and I, myself, had these ideas too when I started to learn JS and PHP. It becomes clearer when you finally tell yourself that it's a bad idea and that server-side and client-side technologies each have their responsibilities and capacities, and they should be kept within these bounds.

Comment: Thank you for referring to my article on 'Creating a simple REST API in PHP'. You may also check out the full featured REST script on [Github](https://github.com/mevdschee/php-crud-api).

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is: you can't.

PHP executes on the server and JavaScript executes on the client.  Once the page reaches the browser all of the PHP has been interpreted.  Your best bet is to AJAX requests to a service that returns JSON, then process and display using JavaScript.

Comment: In some of my snippets i am actively using it. And to minimise the number of files i also used a `tag` in my POST request to fire only required snippets. Was looking for more pretty way.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you wish to load certain pieces of your web page using PHP in some places.  It can be done but it's complicated in my experience, and not ideal.  Here's an non-code explanation of what you can do.

1. Render your HTML/JavaScript page using PHP.  (example.php)
2. Have a JavaScript function that calls a PHP page using Ajax.  The PHP page you call should just echo all the HTML you want to have dynamically be created.  You can just make a large string variable and echo it once you've got it all ready to return.  The echo will be returned to JavaScript's Ajax call. (example_ajax.php which generates the HTML you want and echoes it back)
3. Use the response JavaScript received from example_ajax.php as needed to update your page.

Comment: This is exactly what i am doing right now. And i agree this is ugly.

Comment: @unkn0wn that is your only choice. The client-side (backbone) JavaScript runs in the client browsers, and your PHP code runs on your server. The way they communicate is via HTTP.