# Insert Data into Mysql using Javascript without PHP

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I want to store data into mysql table using JavaScript. But, I don't want to use php. Is it possible?

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3020751/can-javascript-connect-with-mysql

Comment: you might want to use node js that might help you interact with the server using java script

Comment: You can use any language you want on the server side.

Comment: Just curious: why not php?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can JavaScript connect with MySQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3020751/can-javascript-connect-with-mysql)

Comment: Strawberry: This maybe very stupid, but when I try to access the index.php page, the browser tries to download it as opposed to opening it. I hope might understood what I meant.

Answer (score 1):

Javascript is a client-side language, so it runs on the clients browser. If you still want to insert into mysql using javascript then you could use something like node.js which would run on the server-side.

For instance this is how an insert using node.js would look like:

```
var post  = {id: 1, title: 'Hello MySQL'};
var query = connection.query('INSERT INTO posts SET ?', post, function(err, result) {
    // check result or error!
});
```

Comment: actually I want to use it only for like counter, I mean i want to increment in like counter. I hope you might understand what I want to do .. further is it a good approach to use node.js for only like counter ?

Comment: @Jahangir what is it that you would like to count?

Comment: as I said above. I want to count "likes" of a video on my webpage.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to consider Node Js for such job. Check [this](https://www.w3schools.com/nodejs/nodejs_mysql_insert.asp)

Comment: This is not the answer. It should be a comment

Answer (score 0):

Jahangir jan, It's not possible to use client side Javascript to store something into the MySQL. But it's possible to use server side Javascript to do it.

Comment: Yes nodejs is a server side Javascript language so you can communicate with database as well.