# Javascript Syntax Error using MYSQL commands

Tags: javascript, mysql, body-parser

I'm receiving SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token for the line:

```
var databaseQuery = "INSERT INTO userinfo
```

I was wondering if someone could help me format my code because this is my first time using MYSQL and javascript so I'm not sure why this isn't working or if I'm using the right format because I've seen different examples on google and wasn't sure which is the right way to write this.

```
app.post('/registration', urlencodedParser, function(req, res) {
console.log(req.body);
var databaseQuery = "INSERT INTO userinfo
                    (firstName,lastName,email,birthmonth,birthday,birthyear,university,country,state,zip,password)
                    VALUES ('"
                        + req.body.firstName +"','"
                        + req.body.lastName +"','"
                        + req.body.email +"','"
                        + req.body.birthmonth +"','"
                        + req.body.birthday +"','"
                        + req.body.birthyear +"','"
                        + req.body.university +"','"
                        + req.body.country +"','"
                        + req.body.state +"','"
                        + req.body.zip +"','"
                        + req.body.password +"')";

connection.query(databaseQuery, function(err, result) {
    if (err) {
        throw err;
    }else{
        console.log(result.affectedRows + "records updated.");
    }
}
res.render('registration', {qs: req.query});
});
```

Comment: r u sure javascript can call to mysql?

Comment: In JS string literals cannot span over multiple lines. Also, check for prepared statements: at the moment your code is a subject to sql injection vulnerability.

Comment: It would be dirty but try to write the whole query in a single line and see if error persist?

Comment: JavaScript cannot directly call MySql. Please check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3020751/can-javascript-connect-with-mysql

Comment: @AsthaSrivastava probably his `query` method might be doing an ajax call to a server.

Answer (score 1):

The syntax errors occur because you're trying to code one statement in multiple lines and it's not allowed.  If you want to do that, then you'll need to use the back tick (`) character in place of the outer double quotes.  You can also use the ${} delimiter inside your string to include any JavaScript code/variables.

I think there's also another syntax error in your connection.query() -- you need a closing ")" to close the callback/anonymous function.

How about this modified version?

```
app.post('/registration', urlencodedParser, function(req, res) {
console.log(req.body);
var databaseQuery = `INSERT INTO userinfo
(firstName,lastName,email,birthmonth,birthday,birthyear,university,country,state,zip,password)
VALUES ('${req.body.firstName}',
        '${req.body.lastName}',
        '${req.body.email}',
        '${req.body.birthmonth}',
        '${req.body.birthday}',
        '${req.body.birthyear}',
        '${req.body.university}',
        '${req.body.country}',
        '${req.body.state}',
        '${req.body.zip}',
        '${req.body.password}')`;
connection.query(databaseQuery, function(err, result) {
    if (err) {
        throw err;
    }else{
        console.log(result.affectedRows + "records updated.");
    }
});
res.render('registration', {qs: req.query});
});
```