# Not connecting to database with node.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, mysql, sql

I'm trying to connect and request queries from my database, but I wanna do it with JavaScript (or jQuery).

I'm trying this:

```
var mysql = require('mysql');

var con = mysql.createConnection({
  host: "localhost",
  user: "myUser",
  password: "myPassword",
  database: "mydb"
});

function GetSqlResult (sql_query) {
  con.connect(function(err) {
    if (err) throw err;
    //Select all customers and return the result object:
    con.query(sql_query, function (err, result, fields) {
      if (err) throw err;
      return result;
    });
  });
};
```

But I get this error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
```

I've tried using using the module "require.js" from this website http://requirejs.org/docs/release/2.2.0/minified/require.js

I still got the same error.

I want a solution for this error (if it exists), not an alternative.

I know that connecting to a database from JavaScript isn't very safe, but I really wanna do it, so I would love for someone to help me, please.

Thank you

Comment: node.js != jquery

Comment: NodeJS code does not run in your browser, it runs on a backend web server. You should run this code using Node. See https://nodejs.org/en/download/ to set it up.

Comment: @Kulix what can i do?

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3020751/can-javascript-connect-with-mysql

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to do without knowing it, is build a RESTful API. In web architecture, you have your front end code (browser javascript) which makes HTTP requests to a backend. That backend will connect to the database and run queries. Even if you wanted to do this from browser javascript, your browser wouldn't let you. I would recommend you write a REST Api using NodeJS, and have your browser javascript make HTTP requests to that backend. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

NodeJS is not jquery, nodeJs  it runs on a backend web server.

you can use **Meteor** for connecting to database from the client side.