# does mySQL database work separate from programming languages

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql

**I want to make sure about somethings**

if I build a project and use SQL database like MySql

- do I have to work with javascript and Mysql separately
- should I manage a database using a programming language like python or javascript(node)
- do I should make CRUD using javascript to Mysql and create a table and database it from MySql
- I'm new in SQL database Should I create for instance some functionality for a database in order to some stuff with it

finally, if you have any experience working with SQL give any information working with for instance javascript and Mysql

Comment: You can access the same database with different programming languages.

Comment: could I use all SQL commands in javascript

Comment: It depends what kind of JavaScript you mean. Not from JavaScript running in a browser, no. Only from a server-side framework like NodeJS could you do that. What kind of application are you thinking of writing? Will it be a web application, or a desktop one?

Comment: Web application

Comment: ok. So you will likely have some JavaScript running in your browser. That can be used to manipulate the user interface and also, if necessary to communicate with the server via AJAX requests (or you can just use normal links and forms...up to you). When the browser makes a request to the server, that should trigger some server-side code to run (whether that's asp.net, php, python, NodeJS, Java or whatever you choose). That server-side code can then connect to your SQL database to create, update, delete or read data, and then return the results back to the browser.

Comment: If you wish, you can implement some of your code logic in the database itself, in the form of views, functions and stored procedures. You can use those in cases where doing the necessary calculations is more efficient using SQL than it would be to do it using regular code. So you have a lot of options, a lot to consider and potentially a lot to learn. If you've never done this before, my advice would be to take it one step at a time and start with something very simple and achievable, whereby you can learn the core principles without getting confused by your application's functionality.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> do I have to work with javascript and Mysql separately

Yes

> should I manage a database using a programming language like python or 
>   javascript(node)

You can also consider PHP. Its made for interaction with SQL databases.

Answers to most of Your questions can be found in this thread:
[Can JavaScript connect with MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3020751/can-javascript-connect-with-mysql)