# I need to create a function in javascript where I perform a curl request and then provide inline input

Tags: javascript, node.js, curl

I need to create a function in javascript where I can execute curl command:

```
curl -v -X POST -k -u testUser -d login=testUser2 -d password=123456
```

when i run above command in terminal it will prompt me the password, where I have the to enter the password and then I can login into the database.

I am new to Javascript so I don't know how to do that.

I read some article related to `exec` and `child process` command in Javascript but I didn't find any example that will show how I can implement said behavior. I am adding below the sample that I found on internet:

```
const { exec } = require('child_process');

export const executeCommand = (cmd, successCallback, errorCallback) => {
  exec(cmd, (error, stdout, stderr) => {
    if (error) {
     // console.log(`error: ${error.message}`);
      if (errorCallback) {
        errorCallback(error.message);
      }
      return;
    }
    if (stderr) {
      //console.log(`stderr: ${stderr}`);
      if (errorCallback) {
        errorCallback(stderr);
      }
      return;
    }
    //console.log(`stdout: ${stdout}`);
    if (successCallback) {
      successCallback(stdout);
    }
  });
};
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can JavaScript connect with MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3020751/can-javascript-connect-with-mysql)

Comment: Why are you trying to wrap the mysql cli with JavaScript?

Comment: mysql was just a sample command, I am trying to do a curl request

Comment: Are you running node or is this JavaScript in the browser?

Comment: @epascarello i am running node

Comment: Why are you trying to shell out to the `curl` command line binary when there are many perfectly good libraries (like axios and node-fetch) for making HTTP requests from Node.js?

Comment: I am trying to generate token using curl command which will be used as cookies in the request header in order to file uploadation

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to do it this way write instead of *cmd* your command.

```
const { exec } = require("child_process");

exec("curl -v -X POST -k -u testUser:123456 -d login=testUser2 
", (error, stdout, stderr) => {
    if (error) {
        console.log(`error: ${error.message}`);
        return;
    }
    if (stderr) {
        console.log(`stderr: ${stderr}`);
        return;
    }
    console.log(`stdout: ${stdout}`);
});
```

Comment: but how I will pass the inline password when i run the code, because when I run the curl command in terminal it ask me for password

Comment: you can try this 

You can also include a password in the command, but your password will appear in the bash history:

curl -u username:password http://example.co

Comment: curl -u username:password, then it will not prompt for the password. https://programming.vip/docs/use-a-curl-with-a-username-and-password.html